# Android BillingClient Проверить наличие подписки у пользователя

Tags: android, in-app-purchases, android-billing

Логика такова, если оформлена подписка, View subscribe_alert удаляется с content, иначе при нажатии на subscribeBtn, которая находится на subscribe_alert вылазит окно подписки от гугла. Оформление подписки работает, а вот проверить при каждом заходе в приложение наличие этой подписки не получается. Вот код:

```
initBillingClient();

    if(!checkSubscribtion()) {

        subscribeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startBillingClientConnection();
            }
        });
    } else {
        content.removeView(subscribe_alert);
    }
```

Методы:

```
private void initBillingClient() {
    initPurchaseUpdateListenear();

    mBillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this).setListener(listener).build();
}
private void startBillingClientConnection() {

    mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBillingSetupFinished(@BillingClient.BillingResponse int billingResponseCode) {
            if (billingResponseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
                getBillingPurchases();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
            // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
            // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.

        }
    });
private boolean checkSubscribtion() {
    Purchase.PurchasesResult result = mBillingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);

    for(Purchase p : result.getPurchasesList()) {
        if(p.getSku().equals("subid"))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Как нужно проверять наличие подписки?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы проверить наличие подписки у пользователя, можно использовать следующий код на Котлин

Проверяем необходимость отключения подписки (т.е. callback `unsubscribe` будет вызван когда подписка не находится на автопродлении и юзер ее отменил). Стоит учитывать, что подписка все еще может быть действующей, но уже быть отключенной от автопродления

```
fun checkDisableSubscription(context: Context, unsubscribe: () -> Unit) {
    getPurchases(context) { code, list ->
        if (list.isNotEmpty()) {
            val unsubscribed = list.none { it.isAutoRenewing }
            if (unsubscribed) {
                unsubscribe.invoke()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Метод для получения списка всех подписок

```
fun getPurchases(context: Context, onPurchased: (code: Int, purchases: List<Purchase>) -> Unit) {
    val client = BillingClient.newBuilder(context)
        .setListener { responseCode, purchases ->
            onPurchased.invoke(responseCode, purchases?.toMutableList() ?: emptyList())
        }
        .build()

    client.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {
        override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {

        }

        override fun onBillingSetupFinished(responseCode: Int) {
            val result = client.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS)
            onPurchased.invoke(result.responseCode, result.purchasesList ?: emptyList())
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Не могли бы вы привести пример как это код используется? Как например таким образом: if(!isSubscribed()) {addContent()} else {disableContent}
И перевести пример на Java, а то адаптировать не получается, а проект на Java